# Why is using tanh definition of logistic sigmoid faster than scipy's expit?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using a logistic sigmoid for an application. I compared the times using the `scipy.special` function, `expit`, versus using the hyperbolic tangent definition of the sigmoidal.

I found that the hyperbolic tangent was 3 times as fast. What is going on here? I also tested times on a sorted array to see if the result was any different.

Here is an example that was run in IPython:

```
In [1]: from scipy.special import expit

In [2]: myexpit = lambda x: 0.5*tanh(0.5*x) + 0.5

In [3]: x = randn(100000)

In [4]: allclose(expit(x), myexpit(x))
Out[4]: True

In [5]: timeit expit(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.2 ms per loop

In [6]: timeit myexpit(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.94 ms per loop

In [7]: y = sort(x)

In [8]: timeit expit(y)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop

In [9]: timeit myexpit(y)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.37 ms per loop
```

---

#### Edit:

Machine info:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- RAM: 7.4 GB
- Intel Core i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4

Numpy/Scipy info:

```
In [1]: np.__version__
Out[1]: '1.12.0'

In [2]: np.__config__.show()
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

In [3]: import scipy

In [4]: scipy.__version__
Out[4]: '0.18.1'
```

Comment: My guess is that usually `numpy` and `scipy` work on **arrays**. They also allow to work on singulars, but the check, etc. requires some time. Furthermore it takes some time to talk to the backend for `numpy`. Therefore it only pays off to use `numpy` to process data in bulk: calculate the `cos(..)` of thousands of elements, not a single one.

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce on my machine (MacBook Pro, OS X 10.10): I get 1.02 ms per loop for `expit` and 1.29 ms per loop for the `tanh`-based version.

Comment: BTW, what version of SciPy are you using? It looks like the implementation [changed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/6146) recently.

Comment: Mark, I updated to scipy `0.19` and numpy to `1.12.1`. Both run-times decreased. `expit` gets 9.5 ms and `myexpit` gets 3.2 ms. This is strange.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. What are the relative timings of `np.exp` and `np.tanh` on a large array on your machine? (On mine, `tanh` is about 1.5 times slower than `exp`.) BTW, the accuracy of your `myexpit` will suffer for large negative inputs.

Comment: I get 989 µs for `myexpit(x)` and 774 µs for `expit(x)`.  Also, the tanh-based function loses precision in the negative tail:  `myexpit(-40)` gives 0.0, but `expit(-40)` gives 4.2483542552915889e-18, which matches the exact value when limited to 64 bit floating point.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, good idea `exp` times at 8.92 ms while `tanh` times at 3 ms for input of the same shape as my original question. This isolates the issue more, but I'm puzzled as to why it would be the case, since the definition of `tanh` of course involves `exp`. I can't seem to find the source for `tanh` in numpy to determine how it's actually computed. @Warren, thanks -- that is good info.

Comment: For me `expit` wins over `myexpit` by a small margin. 

`%timeit expit(xn)`
`4.12 ms per loop`

while 
`%timeit myexpit(xn)`
`5.23 ms per loop`

Comment: Can you try to do the time tests, after executing this command: `os.system("taskset -p 0xff %d" % os.getpid())`  from ipython terminal

Comment: "I can't seem to find the source for tanh in numpy" <- NumPy should be using your OS math library for both `exp` and `tanh`, so this may come down to `glibc`.

Comment: @kmario23, same result! @Mark, you are correct! I wrote some C++ code operating over a large array. I timed it separately for `exp` and `tanh`, and the `tanh` code runs ~3x as fast. Now, I must figure out why that is the case. Not sure how this question should be answered now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### edit:

I'll refer future people to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045114/why-tanh-is-faster-than-exp-on-my-machine).

---

To summarize results from helpful comments:

> "Why is using tanh definition of logistic sigmoid faster than scipy's expit?"

Answer: It's not; there's some funny business going on with the `tanh` and `exp` C functions on my specific machine.

It's turns out that on my machine, the C function for `tanh` is faster than `exp`. The answer to why this is the case obviously belongs to a different question. When I run the C++ code listed below, I see

```
tanh: 5.22203
exp: 14.9393
```

which matches the ~3x increase in the `tanh` function when called from Python. The strange thing is that when I run the identical code on a separate machine that has the same OS, I get similar timing results for `tanh` and `exp`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double a = -5;
    double b =  5;
    int N =  10001;
    double x[10001];
    double y[10001];
    double h = (b-a) / (N-1);

    clock_t begin, end;

    for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
        x[i] = a + i*h;

    begin = clock();

    for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
        for(int j=0; j < N; j++)
            y[i] = tanh(x[i]);

    end = clock();

    cout << "tanh: " << double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";

    begin = clock();

    for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
        for(int j=0; j < N; j++)
            y[i] = exp(x[i]);

    end = clock();

    cout << "exp: " << double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think your analysis is not correct. I observe a similar issue on my machine, and I think it is cause by the `if` in the scipy expit definition. Running your script above I exp is faster in C++ than tanh. But running the python snippet I get a 3x speedup from using tanh over expit.

Comment: The C code above consistently produced the timing results above on the machine on which it was run. Unfortunately that machine died. Apparently there was some instruction available on that machine that allowed a faster `tanh` computation.