# Why tanh is faster than exp on my machine?

Tags: c++

This question spawned from a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033593/why-is-using-tanh-definition-of-logistic-sigmoid-faster-than-scipys-expit), which turned out to have some apparently machine specific quirks. When I run the C++ code listed below for recording the timing differences between `tanh` and `exp`, I see the following result:

```
tanh: 5.22203
exp: 14.9393
```

`tanh` runs ~3x as fast as `exp`. This is somewhat surprising considering the mathematical definition of `tanh` (and being ignorant of the algorithmic definition implemented).

What's more is that this happens on my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04, Intel Core i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4), but does not occur on my desktop (same OS, not sure about CPU specs right now).

I compiled the code below with `g++`. The above times were with no compiler optimization, although the trend remains if I use `-On` for each `n`. I also fiddled with `a` and `b` values to see if the range of values being evaluated was having an effect. This doesn't seem to matter.

**What would cause `tanh` to be faster than `exp` on different machines?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double a = -5;
    double b =  5;
    int N =  10001;
    double x[10001];
    double y[10001];
    double h = (b-a) / (N-1);

    clock_t begin, end;

    for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
        x[i] = a + i*h;

    begin = clock();

    for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
        for(int j=0; j < N; j++)
            y[i] = tanh(x[i]);

    end = clock();

    cout << "tanh: " << double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";

    begin = clock();

    for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
        for(int j=0; j < N; j++)
            y[i] = exp(x[i]);

    end = clock();

    cout << "exp: " << double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

---

#### edit: some assembly output

[This is output](https://pastebin.com/6BD7nzsk) when I compile the following simplified code below with `g++ -g -O -Wa,-aslh nothing2.cpp > stuff.txt`.

```
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    double x = 0.0;
    double y,z;
    y = tanh(x);
    z = exp(x);
    return 0;
}
```

#### edit: another update

Assume `nothing2.cpp` contains the simplified code in the previous edit. I run:

```
g++ -o nothing2.so -shared -fPIC nothing2.cpp
objdump -d nothing2.so > stuff.txt
```

[Here is the contents of `stuff.txt`](https://pastebin.com/DvEqrNn0)

Comment: Well who knows. Post the asm of exp and tanh, then I'll tell you.

Comment: Would this be the output of compiling with `-S`?

Comment: Despite the hyperbolic trig functions being mathematically defined in terms of exponentiation, they don't have to be implemented using exp. They can be approximated with polynomials.

Comment: @harold, thanks, see edit.

Comment: `tanh` has a fairly small range of interesting values, so you can approximate it to be linear for values great than +-1 ish, compared to `exp` which you have to still calculate these values.

Comment: @harold, I output the assembly using a different command. I don't work with assembly, so if there's a direct way to observe the assembly used by the mathematical functions, let me know.

Comment: It seems GCC does not want to show code from libraries, but you can compile it and then objdump it (using "-d -m intel" please)

Comment: `-m intel` doesn't work, and when I run `objdump` without `-m intel`, the lines for tanh and exp are not informative -- it's just a line with `call ...`.

Comment: The actual function should be in there somewhere, it's not in an .so is it?

Comment: You're right, @harold, I was disassembling a `.o` file because I'm like a toddler pressing random buttons right now. I've updated once more with a link to the disassembly of a `.so`. This output appears to have more detail.

Answer (score 3):

There is various possible explanation and the one applicable in your case depends on which platform you're using or exact which math library that is in use. But one possible explanation is:

First of all the calculation of `tanh` does not rely on the standard definition of `tanh` instead one expresses it in terms of `exp(-2*x)` or `expm1(2*x)` which means one only have to calculate one exponential which is probably the heavy operation (in addition there's a division and some additions).

Second which may be the trick is that for largish values of `x` this will reduce to `(exp(2*x)-1)/(exp(2*x)+1) = 1 - 2/(expm1(2*x)+2)`. The advantage here is that since the second term is smallish it doesn't have to be calculated to the same relative accuracy to get the same final accuracy. This translate into that one wouldn't need the of `expm1` here as in general.

Also for smalish values of `x` there's a similar trick in rewriting it as `(1-exp(-2*x))/(1+exp(-2*x)) = - 1/ (1 + 2/(expm1(-2*x)+2)` which again means that we can take advantage of the factor `exp(-2*x)` being large and not having to calculate it to the same accuracy. However you don't have to actually calculate it this way, you use the expression `expm1(-2*x)/(2+expm1(-2*x))` instead with the same accuracy requirement on `expm1`.

In addition there are other optimizations available for larger values of `x` that isn't possible for `exp` of basically the same origin. With large `x` the factor `expm1(2*x)` will become so large that we can simply discard it entirely, while for `exp` we still have to calculate it (this is even the case for large negative `x`). For these values `tanh` would be immediately decided to be `1` while `exp` must be calculated.

Comment: Thanks, I considered that large values might be optimized. However, you'll notice that in my code that I tested over the range [-5,5] (which shouldn't be cut off to -1 or +1), and that I mentioned testing different ranges. I also observed the same time discrepancy for [-1, 1] and [-0.1, 0.1]. If I test a large range, say [-100,100], the effect is more pronounced (likely due to optimizations you mention), and tanh is ~9x as fast as exp.

Comment: Yes. I completed the answer with "smallish" values too (lower than 1, but not to close to zero). That it's faster for large values is a no-brainer though.

Comment: @harold Yes, but how relevant is that in this case? Note that you also have `exp(x) = 1+x` for small enough `x`.

Comment: @harold The irrelevance is because this applies to only 0.01% of the calculations and that the difference lies in the difference between returning `x` and `x+1`, add to this all other operations that are being done in the iteration the contribution of the addition needed for `exp` is negligible at most.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139240/discussion-between-skyking-and-harold).